# 'Task Home.HomeButton_ClickAsync has the wrong return type' when using async c#

Tags: c#

The Code:

```
    private async Task HomeMoreButton_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InfoLabel_YearOfRelease.Show();

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var Json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=......=" + InfoNameOfShow.Text
             + "&type=" + InfoTypeOfShow.Text.ToLower());
            var ShowsExtendedInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ShowsExtendedInfo>(Json);

            InfoLabel_YearOfRelease.Text = ShowsExtendedInfo.Year;
        }
    }
```

Error:

> **CS0407** 'Task Home.HomeMoreButton_ClickAsync(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type

On Line:

> this.HomeMoreButton.Click += new 
>   System.EventHandler(**this.HomeMoreButton_ClickAsync**);

---

I have moved around things, but have never had this error and couldn't find anything online which helped me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers must be `async void`
see [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Great resource, I found figure two really helped with the problem I was especially having.